# How to generate an array with JSON.stringify from all nodes

Tags: javascript, json

I am new to javascript and can not get all nodes of the table to array using JSON.stringify, and get all in one json.

```
 <ul class="br">
   <li class="txt">
      <table class="texte">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Albert</a></td>
               <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">red</span></td>
                <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">1111</span></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </li>
   <li class="txt">
      <table class="texte">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Beatriz</a></td>
               <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">blue</span></td>
                <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">222</span></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </li>
   <li class="txt">
      <table class="texte">
         <tbody>
            <tr>
               <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Carlos</a></td>
               <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">green</span></td>
                <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">33</span></td>
            </tr>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </li> 
</ul>
```

But my output only generates the first element of the array.

```
    output
{
    "fistName": "Albert",
    "color": "red",
    "telephone": "1111"
}
```

My desired output is like this:

```
{

{
  "fistName": "Albert",
"color": "red",
"telephone": "1111"
},
{
 "fistName": "Beatriz",
"color": "blue",
"telephone": "222"
},
{
 "fistName": "Carlos",
"color": "green",
"telephone": "333"
}
```

}

How do I generate all in json?

Comment: Where is the code that currently generates only the data from the first row?

Comment: You need all the nodes or just the `<td>` ones? your current output shows that your are trying to get the `class` and then the `textContent` as the value.. not enough information

Comment: WIthout sharing the code you have it's hard for anybody to tell you what part you are doing wrong. Since you have the output for 1 element, you are probably on the right track.

Comment: I wanted to generate a json with all nodes, with output like this:
{

    {
      "fistName": "Albert",
 "color": "red",
 "telephone": "1111"
    },
 {
     "fistName": "Beatriz",
 "color": "blue",
 "telephone": "222"
    },
 {
     "fistName": "Carlos",
 "color": "green",
 "telephone": "333"
    }
  
}

Comment: so, not all nodes (at least not all DOM element nodes), just the nodes from the table inside the `<tr>` right?

Comment: @ThgMixer: That isn't actually JSON. I assume you mean the outer `{...}` to be `[...]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it might look something like this. You first select the parent element (the tables with the class `texte`), then you iterate through that collection selecting the elements containing each piece of information you need under the parent and turn that into an object:

```js
var items = document.querySelectorAll("table.texte");
var obj = [].slice.call(items).map(i => {
  var name = i.querySelector(".fistName").textContent;
  var color = i.querySelector(".myColor").textContent;
  var telephone = i.querySelector(".telephone").textContent;
  return {
    name : name,
    color : color,
    telephone : telephone
  };
})

console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
```

```html
<ul class="br">
  <li class="txt">
    <table class="texte">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Albert</a></td>
          <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">red</span></td>
          <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">1111</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li class="txt">
    <table class="texte">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Beatriz</a></td>
          <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">blue</span></td>
          <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">222</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li class="txt">
    <table class="texte">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Carlos</a></td>
          <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">green</span></td>
          <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">33</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

loop through the `tr`, get the `childNodes`, fill the object with the innerText and push it to the result :

```js
let result = [];

document.querySelectorAll('tr').forEach(tr => {
  let obj = {}
  tr.childNodes.forEach(td => {

    td.classList != undefined && (obj[td.classList[0]] = td.innerText)

  })
  result.push(obj)
});

console.log(result)
```

```html
<ul class="br">
  <li class="txt">
    <table class="texte">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Albert</a></td>
          <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">red</span></td>
          <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">1111</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li class="txt">
    <table class="texte">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Beatriz</a></td>
          <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">blue</span></td>
          <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">222</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
  <li class="txt">
    <table class="texte">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td class="fistName"><a href="#">Carlos</a></td>
          <td class="myColor"><span class="bt bu">green</span></td>
          <td class="telephone"><span class="bt bu">33</span></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </li>
</ul>
```